# How to retain special characters like $, £ while extracting text from a website?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using `scrapy` to scrape an example website. This is the webpage - [booksquotes](https://books.toscrape.com/index.html). In order to extract data I am using xpath selectors. Specifically for getting the price of a particular book I use the folllowing xpath - `//*[@id="default"]/div[1]/div/div/div/section/div[2]/ol/li[1]/article/div[2]/p[1]/text()`

Now when I extract the price the £ symbol is omitted since I use `.get()`. I am assuming that `.get()` returns `Unicode` and thus returns a character `\u00a3`. I read the answers to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032653/scrapy-extract-text-with-special-characters) but couldn't follow since the example uses `extract` and not `get`. I also tried using `.encode()` as mentioned in the comments but that returned an empty JSON. Please advise.

Comment: Does the site you are scraping use a different encoding, and perhaps claiming that it's using UTF-8? What are the actual bytes you pull down? (Probably just a small hex dump with a few characters of context around the problematic string should suffice.) See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: Which is "this similar question"? Link please?

Comment: @tripleee edited the question to include the similar question.

Comment: Again, please show the problematic data and enough code to see how you attempt to save it, ideally reduced down to a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Put this below `start_urls` in your spider

```
custom_settings = { 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING' : 'utf-8' }
```

JSON is not encoded to utf-8 automatically, you have to set this.